# Error with creating Document Library in SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I got this error while creating a document library in sharepoint.

**A list, survey, discussion board, or document library with the specified title already exists in this Web site. Please choose another title.**

Here is my coding.

```
                SPSite site = new SPSite(url);
                SPWeb oWebsite = site.OpenWeb();
                oWebsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                Guid customListID = oWebsite.Lists.Add(docLibraryName, docLibraryName, SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);
                oWebsite.Update();
                oWebsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

**forget to mention that there is no such document library with the name I am trying to add.**

Comment: The error message is quite explicit: there is already a list with the same title as the one you want to create. Either destroy the existing list, or change your title. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ohh Sorry to forget to mention that there is no such document library with the name I add.

Comment: Are you absolutely, positively *sure* of that? Maybe the list exists but you don't have the rights necessary to see it? Can you try opening the site with SharePoint Designer (if you have that tool) and browse the lists from there?

Comment: No it does not exist for 100% because I can go to the site and can create a document library with this name and delete it. It only shows when I run my code.

Comment: What do you get if you try to retrieve the doclib via code (`oWebSite.Lists[docLibraryName];`)? Is the `SPWeb` opened the expected web?

Comment: SPWeb the the expected web. How should I tried your code ?
I has 3 SPSites, it only happens on one Site, not on 2 other Sites.

Comment: Is it possible that you are using one of the reserved names, such as "Images", "Forms", or that during to naming convention, the list name (generated from the list Title) is already used?

Comment: No, I tried with **Temporary Document Library**. I can create and delete this document library manually. It only happens when I run my code.

Answer (score 4):

Use SharePoint designer and connect to that site. You may find that a folder with that name has been created which is causing the code to think that the list already exists. Delete that folder and you should be all set.

Comment: It works for me. I've deleted picture library that had been created by ListInstance definition. but the folder with the same url still resided within the site. so SharePoint designer showed the folder and allowed to delete it.

Comment: You, sir, saved my life. Thank you